# Google App Script - WRITE FROM GOOGLE SHEETS TO CLOUD SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to write data from a column in google sheets to a table in cloud sql.

Error is:

"Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for Jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.setString."

On line

```
stmt.setString('' + CopyData[i][0]);
```

I'm very new to google app script and have VERY limited knowledge of mySQL. Done a web development course in college about 10 years ago and havent looked at it since.

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
function WriteToDB() {

  var connectionName = 'xxx';
  var user = 'xxx';
  var userPwd = 'xxx1';
  var db = 'TestDB';
  var instanceUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName;
  var dbUrl = instanceUrl + '/' + db;
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
      conn.setAutoCommit(false);

  var SS_File = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SourceSheet = SS_File.getSheetByName("WorkSheet1");

  var headerRowNumber = 1;
  var CopyData = SourceSheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, SourceSheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues();

 var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO TestTable ' +  '(TestColumn) VALUES (?)');

 for (var i = 0; i < CopyData.length; i++) {
  stmt.setString('' + CopyData[i][0]);
  stmt.addBatch();
}

  var batch = stmt.executeBatch();
  conn.comit();
  conn.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %s ms for %s rows.', end - start, batch.length);
}
```

The connection is OK, I can create table etc through app script. Just can't write this data.

The data is in column A on the spreadsheet, header row is 1.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Ive tried

```
 for (var i = 0; i < CopyData.length; i++) {
  stmt.setObject(i, CopyData[i][0]);
  stmt.addBatch();
```

Error: "Exception: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 )"

&

```
 for (var i = 0; i < CopyData.length; i++) {
  stmt.setObject(i+1, CopyData[i][0]);
  stmt.addBatch();
```

Error: "Exception: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)"

&

```
 for (var i = 0; i < CopyData.length; i++) {
  stmt.setObject(i, CopyData[i]);
  stmt.addBatch();
```

Error: "Exception: Invalid argument value: java.sql.SQLException"

Stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

WORKING CODE FOR ANYBODY TO USE IN THE FUTURE.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

ONLY PROBLEM I HAVE IS THAT CLOUD SQL TIME-OUT RESTRICTIONS. - Working to resolve this, will provide solution once I solve the problem.

NOTE: MAKE SURE VALUES IN SOURCE SHEET ARE STRINGS, NO FORMULAS.

I had to copy values to another sheets using copy.to(xxx, {contentsonly:true}).

```
function WriteToDB() {

var connectionName = 'YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME';
var user = 'YOUR_USERNAME';
var userPwd = 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
var db = 'YOUR_DATABASE';
var instanceUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName;
var dbUrl = instanceUrl + '/' + db;

  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);

  var SS_File = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SourceSheet = SS_File.getSheetByName("YOUR_SHEET_NAME");

  var headerRowNumber = 1; // HOW MANY ROWS TO MISS
  var CopyData = SourceSheet.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, SourceSheet.getLastRow() - headerRowNumber).getValues();

 var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME " +  "(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME) VALUES (?)");
    for (var i = 0; i < CopyData.Length; i++) {
        stmt.setString(1, CopyData[i][0]);
        stmt.addBatch();
    }
  var batch = stmt.executeBatch();
  conn.commit();
  conn.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I tried using batches and had no success so I go row by row and performance is still good.

I start by build the basic string:

```
var stmtStr = "INSERT INTO TestTable (TestColumn) VALUES (";
```

Then work with a copy of the basic string in the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < CopyData.length; i++) {
   query = stmtStr + CopyData[i][0] + ")";
   stmt = conn.createStatement();
   iUpdate = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
   if (i==0) {
     console.log(query, iUpdate, CopyData[i][0]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Still no joy.
"Exception: Unknown column 'AC' in 'field list'"

 Theres about 4000 rows to copy so I think I'll need to batch anyway.

Thanks

Comment: I do not feel you need to use batch, I update thousands on a daily basis on multiple tables. So, is "AC" a column name in your MySQL db? Perhaps show the real code removing the logon info to your db as you example refers to TestTable and TestColumn. What type is the column (varchar)? Have you inspected the array CopyData in the debugger?

Comment: Hi mate.
I've solved it and added working batch code so you can use in future.
Thanks for the help, appreciated!